# Getting EXEC_BAD_ACCES after leaving IBAction

Tags: core-data, exc-bad-access, ibaction

Im trying to fetch information from a SQLlite database with Core Data and just after leaveing the IBAction that get the NSManageObject from DB the App crash with only a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The code executed is:

```
- (IBAction)abrir:(id)sender{
[openBrowser setTag:[sender tag]];
[self showOpenPanel:mWindow];
if (acceptCancelButton) {
    NSString *auxN;
    NSPredicate *auxP;
    NSFetchRequest *auxFR;
    NSError *err;
    NSArray *array;
    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
            auxN = [[[openBrowser selectedCell] stringValue] copy];
            auxP =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studyName == %@", auxN];
            auxFR = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [auxFR setPredicate:auxP];
            [auxFR setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Study" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
            [auxFR setIncludesSubentities:NO];
            [auxFR setFetchLimit:1];
            array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:auxFR error:&err];
            if(array){
                /*
                 Instanciamos un nuevo nsmanagedobject y lo cargamos con la información
                 leida de la BD
                 */
                actualStudy = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Study" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                [actualStudy setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"studyName"] forKey:@"studyName"];
                [actualStudy setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"studyPath"] forKey:@"studyPath"];
                [actualStudy setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"studyDescription"] forKey:@"studyDescription"];
                [actualStudy setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"compressRate"] forKey:@"compressRate"];
                [actualStudy setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"testDuration"] forKey:@"testDuration"];
                NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %d %d", 
                      [actualStudy valueForKey:@"studyName"],
                      [actualStudy valueForKey:@"studyPath"],
                      [actualStudy valueForKey:@"studyDescription"],
                      [[actualStudy valueForKey:@"compressRate"] floatValue],
                      [[actualStudy valueForKey:@"testDuration"] intValue]);
            }else{
                [Auxiliar showError:-15];
            }
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

}

- actualStudy is a variable of @interface Study : NSManagedObject {

The code execute normaly but when the app return from the call give this message:

```
The Debugger has exited with status 0.
[Session started at 2016-03-16 15:23:07 +0000.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1515) (Sat Jan 15 08:33:48 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".
tty /dev/ttys001
Loading program into debugger…
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreData" (not yet mapped into memory).
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 3574]
Running…
[Switching to process 3574]
[Switching to process 3574]
[Switching to process 3574]
[Switching to process 3574]
(gdb) continue
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++
(gdb) continue
2016-03-16 15:23:36.720 eTracker[3574:a0f] CoreData /Users/admin/usabilimac/build/Debug/CoreData/ Prueba core data 600 0
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb)
```

That the exec pile:

```
#0  0x7fff88de6f10 in objc_msgSend
#1  0x7fff836101d6 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
#2  0x7fff86d3e110 in -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
#3  0x7fff81e27723 in -[NSApplication run]
#4  0x7fff81e203b0 in NSApplicationMain
#5  0x1000027f1 in main at main.mm:13
```

Comment: I just found that the trouble Its that managedobjectcontext call a release over the array and when leave IBAction another release its sended to the array object. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in other part of the code, but As I said it was the multireleasing of the same array.

After I eliminate all explicit release calls the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS disappeared.

Thanks to all that try to answer my question.